# Who is right and who is wrong aka GCC vs Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, gcc

This code (doesn't "work" correctly) but compiles in VS 2010 but doesn't won't to compile in GCC 4.5.1

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>//not necessary second > should skip like brackets

using namespace std;

template<class ForwardIterator>
void iterator_swap(ForwardIterator& left,ForwardIterator& right)
{
    typename ForwardIterator::value_type tmp = *left;
    *left = *right;
    *right = tmp;
}

template<class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const std::vector<T>& obj)
{
   typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator beg = obj.cbegin();
   typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator end = obj.cend();
    while (beg != end)
    {
        out << *beg << '\n';
        ++beg;
    }
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    vector<unsigned> v_1;
    for (vector<unsigned>::size_type i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        v_1.push_back(i);
    }
    vector<unsigned> v_2;
    for (vector<unsigned>::size_type i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        v_2.push_back(i*10);
    }
    cout << "v_1:\n" << v_1;
    cout << "v_2:\n" << v_2;
    iterator_swap(v_1.begin(),v_2.begin());
    cout << "After swap:\n";
    cout << "v_1:\n" << v_1;
    cout << "v_2:\n" << v_2;
    return 0;
}
```

In GCC I'm getting following err msg:

```
E:\CodeBlocks\Iter_swap\main.cpp|41|error: 
     invalid initialization of non-const reference of type     
       '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned int*, std::vector<unsigned int, 
           std::allocator<unsigned int> > >&' from a temporary of type 
       '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned int*, std::vector<unsigned int, 
           std::allocator<unsigned int> > >'|
```

So which team is right? VS or GCC?

Comment: Why are you passing iterators by reference if you don't intend to modify them?

Comment: +1 The question is worded terribly, but you've stumbled on one of my pet peeves with GCC, and a common problem I'm sure.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
iterator_swap(v_1.begin(),v_2.begin());
```

You're passing a temporary (returned from the `begin()` functions) to a function that accepts two **non-const references**. Standard C++ prohibits temporaries from binding to non-const references. (Standard C++ does allow temporaries to bind to **const** references, however.)

Both GCC [and VC++ (versions 2005 and later) "knows"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cfbk5ddc.aspx) that you can't bind temporaries to non-const references according to standard C++. So they're both "right" per se. However, Visual C++ implements a non-standard extension that allows temporaries to bind to non-const references in the manner you have in your code snippet.

To catch things like this, I highly recommend that you compile your code with [level 4 warnings enabled (`/W4`) and treat warnings as errors (`/WX`) on Visual C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thxezb7y.aspx). It will catch errors like these.

Comment: @In silico so basically VS is wrong (according to std), am I right?

Comment: Personally I think GCC worth more trust, because if it has a bug, its huge user base should guarantee a fix as soon as possible. Microsoft's fix cycle takes much longer.

Comment: +1 So really, the answer is "Neither, you're wrong for not compiling with `/W4`".

Comment: @In silico: `/W4` + `/WX` ? how to you get anything to compile ? It raises heaps of error in the STL implementation for me :/

Comment: @Code Gray since when it is an error not to compile with /w4? Simple pundit, that who you are.

Comment: @There: It is an error to not compile with /W4 and then ask here what is wrong, when the level 4 warning tells you just that.

Comment: @Bo Persson we talking c++ here ok? So you're wrong saying that it is an error not compiling with /w4, and if you're think you're not show me place in the standard that says otherwise. Don't try to be to smart.

Comment: @There: It becomes an error not to compile with all warning enabled when you find yourself asking questions like this. Evidence you're probably trying to outsmart the compiler or writing way too much code that tests the edge cases of the spec. I may be just a simple pundit, but I'm one that compiles with `/W4`.

Comment: @Matthieu M.: I can compile code using STL classes like `std::vector<>` with `/W4` and `/WX` just fine. Then again, I'm using the standard library implementation that came with the VC++ compilers. If you need to, you can wrap the STL headers with [`#pragma warning(push, 3)` and `#pragma warning(pop)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e.aspx) to temporarily suppress level 4 warnings.

Comment: @Cody Gray where in c++ std or VS compiler manual says that it is an error not to compile with /w4?

Comment: @There is nothing we can do: The documentation for `/W4` states that ["For a new project, it may be best to use /W4 in all compilations"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thxezb7y.aspx). It's not a compilation error to not compile at the highest warning level per se, but it is recommended so that you can catch as many errors as the compiler can at compile time. And catching errors at compile time rather than runtime is always a good thing.

Comment: @There is nothing we can do: if we really want to be smart-asses about it, then as far as the standard is concerned it's an "error" to compile C++ with a non-conforming compiler. It's naturally an error to expect two non-conforming compilers to do the same thing, or to suggest that if they don't then one of them must be "wrong". Both GCC and MSVC are *deliberately* non-conforming by default. If you put them into their respective strict modes, then they're conforming as far as they've managed so far, limited by the ingenuity of their respective authors.

Comment: ... so for example MSVC's authors can't get two-phase lookup working in templates (actually - this might be fixed by now as part of their drive to C++0x, I don't know), and neither compiler's authors can implement `export` (nor have they tried AFAIK). But this isn't that kind of problem, and it isn't a bug in either compiler, it's entirely deliberate non-standard behavior. /W4 is one way to make MSVC closer to standard, since it warns you when many of its quirks are used.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: I believe `export` is deprecated in C++0x in favor of extern templates because of the fact no one seems to be actually using it. Only the Comeau C++ compiler supports it, and even Comeau programmers don't use `export`.

Comment: @In silico: I believe the current state of the draft is that the feature's removed, not just deprecated. Certainly Sutter reported on his blog a while back that there was agreement to remove it. I don't think the contents of C++0x are relevant to whether a compiled conforms to C++03, I chose it as a specific (in)famous example where compilers are non-conformant because conformance is just too hard to be worth it. That's to contrast with this case, where MSVC is non-conformant by default because MS engineers prefer that behavior to what the standard says. Standard behavior is also available.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Right. One can argue that MSVC++ is "conformant" by C++ standard 1.4/8: "A conforming implementation may have extensions... provided they do not alter the behavior of any well-formed program. Implementations are required to diagnose programs that use such extensions... however, they can compile and execute such programs." But you are correct that the standard behavior (or at least as close to standard behavior as possible) is available via `/W4` on VC++.

Comment: @in silico: right, MSVC is conformant in this respect if it warns (or refuses to compile, of course, that counts as diagnosis too), non-conformant if it doesn't. So as far as this quirk is concerned, with `/W4` it does and without it (I think) it doesn't.

Comment: @Steve and In silico correct wording is careless behaviour not an error. I thought english is my second language not yours.

Comment: @Steve and why did you put error in quotas? If it is real error it doesn't need them.

Comment: @Steve and where did I say about compiling with non conformant compiler? The only thing I've said is: since when it is an error not to compile with /w4? So if you really wanna be smart ass first read carefully and make sure that you understand what you're reading and don't get off the track trying to talk about something else.

Comment: @Steve and saying something (that std says such and such thing) without providing correct reference is well, simply unprofessional. Show me 'you not so smart ass as you might think you are' where std says that it is an error to not compile with /w4.

Comment: @There is nothing we can do: "I thought english is my second language not yours." Me too, since English happens to be my native language. And in the English language, the word "error" has multiple definitions, but one definition is "a deviation from accuracy or correctness." Not compiling in `/W4` can be seen as a deviation from correctness because `/W4` can warn you of potentially suspect code. In this sense, it is an error since you're better off using `/W4` and fix all warnings.

Comment: @There is nothing we can do: And by the way, the tone of your comments is unwarranted for. Clearly you and Steve Jessop have slightly different definitions of what the word "error" means. That's fine. But it is not grounds for you to throw around ad hominem attacks like my english skills and professional mannerisms. I politely provided an answer, saying that you should compile with `/W4` on VC++ because it will catch the most potential errors. I even provided a link to the official documentation recommending the practice.

Comment: @There is nothing we can do: "correct wording is careless behaviour not an error." This makes no sense. How can correct wording be careless? With respect to the standard, the C++ standard doesn't talk about `/W4` because it's an implementation-specific feature of the Visual C++ compilers, which implements the C++ language. I provided a comment that explained how VC++ can still be conformant with the standard (1.4/8) by turning on `/W4`. Again, official Visual C++ documentation recommends `/W4` for all new projects. What other "official" source do you want?

Comment: @There, @Insilico: Bingo. You keep asking for a link to the "standard" that says you should compile at warning level 4. That's never going to happen, because that's an implementation-defined feature of Microsoft's C++ compiler. Other compliers implement it differently. But the point is, if you're looking for *strict standards compliance*, and hope to eliminate any of the non-standards compliant language extensions generally offered by compiler vendors, you should always compile at the highest warning level.

Comment: @In silico My only objection was to comment of smart ass Cody Grey when he said: So really, the answer is "Neither, you're wrong for not compiling with /W4". And I rightly demanded prove from him to show me where in standard (or in VS compiler manual) says that it is an error not to compile with /w4. As for definition of error word? Here we are concerned with C++ langauge and error should be use in context of this language.

Comment: @In silico, @Cody Grey Read it slowly: Correct wording (of mine practice) is (should be): Careless not error. So in other words one should say, you are **careless** not compiling with /w4, but NOT you are making an error. It is not an error in C++ meaning to compile with different level that /w4. So Cody Grey, stop trying to be smarter than you really are.

Comment: @In silico and does official Visual C++ documentation says that compiling with level other than /w4 is an error?

Comment: @There: There is no such thing as "error in context of the C++ language". The language neither defines the word error nor gives it a contextual meaning. Your argument is nonsensical. More to the point, it went from being merely "careless" to an "error" when you encountered what spurred this question. As I said when you originally asked me to justify myself: "It becomes an error not to compile with all warnings enabled when you find yourself asking questions like this. Evidence you're probably trying to outsmart the compiler or writing way too much code that tests the edge cases of the spec."

Comment: @There: I also don't understand where your fixation on "official documentation" comes from. I *never* made the argument that anything I said is based on official documentation. I don't know why it matters what Microsoft writes about the compiler. The problem is obvious: there is a complier-specific extension that you don't like because it isn't strictly standards-compliant. The way to *resolve* that is by compiling at a higher warning level. You disagree with that solution because it's not recommended in the "official documentation". I'm sorry, but that's just ridiculous.

Comment: @There is nothing we can do: You are making this much more difficult than it needs to be. I should not need 25+ comments to explain this: It's not a compiler/conformance error *per se*, but it is an error in the sense that you'll miss some potential bugs if you don't compile with `/W4`. This is what Cody Gray meant. This is simply an issue with how you and Cody and I define the word "error."

Comment: @There is nothing we can do: Again, you will not get compiler errors if you didn't compile with /W4. But as I explained, an error can mean "a deviation from accuracy or correctness," and not using /W4 is a deviation from correctness because of the possibility of missing suspect code. This is what Cody Gray meant. The fact that you and Cody seem to vehemently disagree on this particular matter is simply because of a misunderstanding of the word "error" between you and Cody. The topic at hand does not justify the personal attacks on character nor this discussion.

Comment: @There is nothing we can do: sorry, if you dish it out, you should expect to take it. You said, "so basically VC is wrong according to std". Cody quite correctly pointed out that you were in error to say so and in error to expect conforming behaviour from a compiler in non-conforming mode. MSDN says (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k0w269d.aspx): "The /Za compiler option emits an error for language constructs that are not compatible with either ANSI C or ANSI C++. The /Ze compiler option, which is the default, enables Microsoft extensions."

Comment: @Cody: "I don't know why it matters what Microsoft writes about the compiler" - I think it matters at the very basic level that the compiler is clearly described in its own documentation not to be standard-conforming with the options the questioner was using. Users who miss this fact and expect strictly conforming behaviour, are of course bound for disappointment. They might as well say that Java compilers are "wrong" for not conforming to the C++ standard, and it would be equally erroneous for them to say such a thing.